# show bootstrap tooltip with custom attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" id="update_user_info" action="/Cabinet/Edit">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="span4 clear_mp">
            <div class="span2 pull-left clear_mp">
                <label for="FirstName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" value="John" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="span1 pull-right clear_mp">
                <label for="CarMark">Car</label>
                <input type="text" value="SUBARU LEGACY" name="CarMark" id="CarMark" />
            </div>          


            <div class="span1 pull-right clear_mp">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" value="test@mail.com" name="Email" id="Email" data-val-email="The email is wrong" data-val="true" class="input-validation-error" />
            </div>
            <div class="span2 pull-left clear_mp">
                <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone number </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" data-val-regex-pattern="(\+)?77[0-9]{9}" data-val-regex="The phone number is wrong" data-val="true" />
                <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="PhoneNumber" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
            </div>

        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="update_user_info" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to do the following:
1. Find `input` which have the class `input-validation-error` (here, I don't have problem)
2. Get the value of `data-val-*` (* means email or regex or something else) attribute and show bootstrap tooltip with this value on the input?

How can I do this?

The markup on the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3KEz/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, what you want to do. Anyway, this might be starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[data-val="true"]').each(function(i, elem){
        var theTitle = '';
        if ( $(elem).data('val-email') ) {
            theTitle = $(elem).data('val-email');
        } else if ( $(elem).data('val-regex') ) {
            theTitle = $(elem).data('val-regex');
        } else {
            theTitle = "Something is wrong here";
        }
        $(elem).tooltip({
            title: theTitle
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3KEz/1/).

The regex pattern isn't executed, because you didn't mention it in your post. So I assumed, that validation is not part of your problem. If it is, you might want to provide some more detail on what exactly you are trying to do.